# Is the Managed heap not scalable to multi-core systems

Tags: c#, .net

I was seeing some strange behavior in a multi threading application which I wrote and which was not scaling well across multiple cores.

The following code illustrates the behavior  I am seeing. It appears the heap intensive operations do not scale across multiple cores rather they seem to slow down. ie using a single thread would be faster.

```
class Program
{
   public static Data _threadOneData = new Data();
   public static Data _threadTwoData = new Data();
   public static Data _threadThreeData = new Data();
   public static Data _threadFourData = new Data();

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Do heap intensive tests
      var start = DateTime.Now;
      RunOneThread(WorkerUsingHeap);
      var finish = DateTime.Now;
      var timeLapse = finish - start;
      Console.WriteLine("One thread using heap: " + timeLapse);

      start = DateTime.Now;
      RunFourThreads(WorkerUsingHeap);
      finish = DateTime.Now;
      timeLapse = finish - start;
      Console.WriteLine("Four threads using heap: " + timeLapse);

      // Do stack intensive tests
      start = DateTime.Now;
      RunOneThread(WorkerUsingStack);
      finish = DateTime.Now;
      timeLapse = finish - start;
      Console.WriteLine("One thread using stack: " + timeLapse);

      start = DateTime.Now;
      RunFourThreads(WorkerUsingStack);
      finish = DateTime.Now;
      timeLapse = finish - start;
      Console.WriteLine("Four threads using stack: " + timeLapse);

      Console.ReadLine();
   }

   public static void RunOneThread(ParameterizedThreadStart worker)
   {
      var threadOne = new Thread(worker);
      threadOne.Start(_threadOneData);

      threadOne.Join();
   }

   public static void RunFourThreads(ParameterizedThreadStart worker)
   {
      var threadOne = new Thread(worker);
      threadOne.Start(_threadOneData);

      var threadTwo = new Thread(worker);
      threadTwo.Start(_threadTwoData);

      var threadThree = new Thread(worker);
      threadThree.Start(_threadThreeData);

      var threadFour = new Thread(worker);
      threadFour.Start(_threadFourData);

      threadOne.Join();
      threadTwo.Join();
      threadThree.Join();
      threadFour.Join();
   }

   static void WorkerUsingHeap(object state)
   {
      var data = state as Data;
      for (int count = 0; count < 100000000; count++)
      {
         var property = data.Property;
         data.Property = property + 1;
      }
   }

   static void WorkerUsingStack(object state)
   {
      var data = state as Data;
      double dataOnStack = data.Property;
      for (int count = 0; count < 100000000; count++)
      {
         dataOnStack++;
      }
      data.Property = dataOnStack;
   }

   public class Data
   {
      public double Property
      {
         get;
         set;
      }
   }
}
```

This code was run on a Core 2 Quad (4 core system) with the following results:

One thread using heap: 00:00:01.8125000

Four threads using heap: 00:00:17.7500000

One thread using stack: 00:00:00.3437500

Four threads using stack: 00:00:00.3750000

So using the heap with four threads did 4 times the work but took almost 10 times as long. This means it would be twice as fast in this case to use only one thread??????

Using the stack was much more as expected.

I would like to know what is going on here. Can the heap only be written to from one thread at a time?

Comment: Its all there look again

Comment: Sorry, scroll bar threw me :)

Comment: I just notices the stack and the heap loop run a different number of times am fixing now...

Comment: @Daniel: Did you run inside Visual Studio?  See my answer for my times...

Comment: @Reed: The difference goes away when run outside visual studio. However see my comment to your answer about the overhead of starting threads.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is simple - run outside of Visual Studio...

I just copied your entire program, and ran it on my quad core system.

Inside VS (Release Build):

```
One thread using heap: 00:00:03.2206779
Four threads using heap: 00:00:23.1476850
One thread using stack: 00:00:00.3779622
Four threads using stack: 00:00:00.5219478
```

Outside VS (Release Build):

```
One thread using heap: 00:00:00.3899610
Four threads using heap: 00:00:00.4689531
One thread using stack: 00:00:00.1359864
Four threads using stack: 00:00:00.1409859
```

Note the difference.  The extra time in the build outside VS is pretty much all due to the overhead of starting the threads.  Your work in this case is too small to really test, and you're not using the high performance counters, so it's not a perfect test.

Main rule of thumb - always do perf. testing outside VS, ie: use Ctrl+F5 instead of F5 to run.

Comment: I ran outside of visual studio and can confirm that the difference goes away. However I do not agree with your reason. The stack tests also starts 4 threads but does not experience the same slowdown when run from visual studio.

Comment: The issue is a visual studio debugging issue, not a stack/heap managed code issue.  Visual Studio's debugger completely eliminates inlining of the property accessors, changes how it attaches to threads, etc.  Your "stack" version is much simpler IL when compiled, since you're doing a single operation in your loop, so it doesn't have the same issues when run inside VS.  Property access is much slower when run in VS than outside VS, esp. threaded property access if you're not using TLS.

Comment: Visual studio is adding tracing code, which is going to severely impact the speed of access of your data objects.  This happens even in release build.

Comment: It looks like running this under VS *or* in debug build is causing the slowdown.

Comment: Both disable the optimizations needed to get reasonable comparisons in the results here.  This is really a debugging side-effect, not a platform bug or issue.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the debug-vs-release effects, there is something more you should be aware of.

***You cannot effectively evaluate multi-threaded code for performance in 0.3s.***

The point of threads is two-fold: effectively model parallel work in code, and effectively exploit parallel resources (cpus, cores).

You are trying to evaluate the latter. Given that thread start overhead is not vanishingly small in comparison to the interval over which you are timing, your measurement is immediately suspect.  In most perf test trials, a significant warm up interval is appropriate. This may sound silly to you - it's a computer program fter all, not a lawnmower. But warm-up is absolutely imperative if you are really going to evaluate multi-thread performance. Caches get filled, pipelines fill up, pools get filled, GC generations get filled. The steady-state, continuous performance is what you would like to evaluate. For purposes of this exercise, the program behaves like a lawnmower.

You could say - *Well, no, I don't want to evaluate the steady state performance.*  And if that is the case, then I would say that your scenario is very specialized.  Most app scenarios, whether their designers explicitly realize it or not, need continuous, steady performance.

If you truly need the perf to be good only over a single 0.3s interval, you have found your answer.  But be careful to not generalize the results.

If you want general results, you need to have reasonably long warm up intervals, and longer collection intervals.  You might start at 20s/60s for those phases, but here is the key thing: you need to vary those intervals until you find the results converging. YMMV. The valid times vary depending on the application workload and the resources dedicated to it, obviously.  You may find that a measurement interval of 120s is necessary for convergence, or you may find 40s is just fine.  But (a) you won't know until you measure it, and (b) you can bet 0.3s is not long enough.

Comment: Good point about the longer interval.  Also, for those kind of multi-thread things, I prefer something that spins up the needed threads, sets a flag and blocks on a Monitor, then once they're all ready, pulses the monitor and starts the time.  Then, have each thread run for a specified amount of time and log the time/count for each, then sum it up.  That way you don't have fairness issues getting in the way and the like.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Run them for a specified amount of time and ideally the number of transactions performed in the interval is large.  Also maybe it is helpful to use a hi-resolution timer instead of DateTime - look into p/invoking QueryPerformanceCounter.

Answer (score 2):

[edit]Turns out, this is a release vs. debug build issue -- not sure why it is, but it is.  See comments and other answers.[/edit]

This was very interesting -- I wouldn't have guessed there'd be that much difference. (similar test machine here -- Core 2 Quad Q9300)

Here's an interesting comparison -- add a decent-sized additional element to the 'Data' class -- I changed it to this:

```
public class Data
{
    public double Property { get; set; }
    public byte[] Spacer = new byte[8096];
}
```

It's still not quite the same time, but it's very close (running it for 10x as long results in 13.1s vs. 17.6s on my machine).

If I had to guess, I'd speculate that it's related to cross-core cache coherency, at least if I'm remembering how CPU cache works.  With the small version of 'Data', if a single cache line contains multiple instances of Data, the cores are having to constantly invalidate each other's caches (worst case if they're all on the same cache line).  With the 'spacer' added, their memory addresses are sufficiently far enough apart that one CPU's write of a given address doesn't invalidate the caches of the other CPUs.

Another thing to note -- the 4 threads start nearly concurrently, but they don't finish at the same time -- another indication that there's cross-core issues at work here.  Also, I'd guess that running on a multi-cpu machine of a different architecture would bring more interesting issues to light here.

I guess the lesson from this is that in a highly-concurrent scenario, if you're doing a bunch of work with a few small data structures, you should try to make sure they aren't all packed on top of each other in memory.  Of course, there's really no way to make sure of that, but I'm guessing there are techniques (like adding spacers) that could be used to try to make it happen.

[edit]
This was too interesting -- I couldn't put it down.  To test this out further, I thought I'd try varying-sized spacers, and use an integer instead of a double to keep the object without any added spacers smaller.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("name\t1 thread\t4 threads");
        RunTest("no spacer", WorkerUsingHeap, () => new Data());

        var values = new int[] { -1, 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 };
        foreach (var sv in values)
        {
            var v = sv;
            RunTest(string.Format(v == -1 ? "null spacer" : "{0}B spacer", v), WorkerUsingHeap, () => new DataWithSpacer(v));
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void RunTest(string name, ParameterizedThreadStart worker, Func<object> fo)
    {
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
        RunOneThread(worker, fo);
        var middle = DateTime.UtcNow;
        RunFourThreads(worker, fo);
        var end = DateTime.UtcNow;

        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", name, middle-start, end-middle);
    }

    public static void RunOneThread(ParameterizedThreadStart worker, Func<object> fo)
    {
        var data = fo();
        var threadOne = new Thread(worker);
        threadOne.Start(data);

        threadOne.Join();
    }

    public static void RunFourThreads(ParameterizedThreadStart worker, Func<object> fo)
    {
        var data1 = fo();
        var data2 = fo();
        var data3 = fo();
        var data4 = fo();

        var threadOne = new Thread(worker);
        threadOne.Start(data1);

        var threadTwo = new Thread(worker);
        threadTwo.Start(data2);

        var threadThree = new Thread(worker);
        threadThree.Start(data3);

        var threadFour = new Thread(worker);
        threadFour.Start(data4);

        threadOne.Join();
        threadTwo.Join();
        threadThree.Join();
        threadFour.Join();
    }

    static void WorkerUsingHeap(object state)
    {
        var data = state as Data;
        for (int count = 0; count < 500000000; count++)
        {
            var property = data.Property;
            data.Property = property + 1;
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int Property { get; set; }
    }
    public class DataWithSpacer : Data
    {
        public DataWithSpacer(int size) { Spacer = size == 0 ? null : new byte[size]; }
        public byte[] Spacer;
    }
}
```

Result:

1 thread vs. 4 threads

- no spacer       00:00:06.3480000        00:00:42.6260000
- null spacer     00:00:06.2300000        00:00:36.4030000
- 0B spacer       00:00:06.1920000        00:00:19.8460000
- 4B spacer       00:00:06.1870000        00:00:07.4150000
- 8B spacer       00:00:06.3750000        00:00:07.1260000
- 12B spacer      00:00:06.3420000        00:00:07.6930000
- 16B spacer      00:00:06.2250000        00:00:07.5530000
- 20B spacer      00:00:06.2170000        00:00:07.3670000

No spacer = 1/6th the speed, null spacer = 1/5th the speed, 0B spacer = 1/3th the speed, 4B spacer = full speed.

I don't know the full details of how the CLR allocates or aligns objects, so I can't speak to what these allocation patterns look like in real memory, but these definitely are some interesting results.

Comment: @Jonathan:  His class is tiny - it's a single double wrapped in a class, with each core getting it's own copy of the class.  This should completely eliminate any memory coherency/caching issues, since each core's working set should fit entirely in that core's cache.  This is more a problem with testing methodology - not threading.  VS is horrible about slowing down threads when you run inside the VS host.

Comment: And of course, I see the other comments and double-check -- sure enough, I forgot to set release mode....

Note: I was seeing all this in a *debug* build *outside* of VS.